# Scraping NYT APi returns status code 401 authentication error

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape NYT API in python3 and storing in MongoDB but I am getting
401 error status authentication error. My code is as below. Any help you can offer is of great assistance to me. Thanks in advance

```
def scrape_arts(coll, last_date):
page = 0
while  page <= 199:
    API_KEY = "api key here"
    print ('Page:', page)
    payload = {'sort':'newest',
               'end_date': get_end_date(last_date),
               'api-key': API_KEY
    }
    r = call_api(NYT_URL, payload, page)
    page += 1
    if r.status_code != 200:
        page = 0
        last_date += relativedelta(days = -1)
        print ('End date:', get_end_date(last_date))
        print (r.status_code)
        continue
        
    meta, docs = get_response(r)
    new_docs = remove_prev_scraps(coll, docs)
    if not new_docs: continue
        
    docs_with_body = get_body(new_docs)
        
    for doc in docs_with_body:
        try:
            coll.insert_one(doc)
        except:
            continue

NYT_URL = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new+york+times&page=2&sort=oldest&api-key='api key here''

with open(r'F:\\School\\2017-18\\Ingenious\\pi_key.txt') as handle:
API_KEY = handle.read()

scrape_arts(articles, last_date)
```

This is the output :

```
Page: 0
End date: 2017/09/19
401
Page: 0
End date: 2017/09/18
401
Page: 0
End date: 2017/09/17
401
```